# i have installed ubuntu 17.04 with all 3rd party software yet my wifi is not showing up in the connections

Tags: networking

I am not able to see any of the wifi networks present.I have a windows 10 and ubuntu running virtually.My network drivers are also not showing in additional drivers section

Comment: That's not how VMs usually work. If the WiFi is in use by the host it will not be available for the guest. The network connection, depending on the VM's specific settings is provided by a virtual device.

Comment: I am using oracle vm virtual box,can you just suggest the required setting change

Comment: The setting to do what exactly?